# ContentProviderClient.insert returning null. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: android

I could use some help on this. This is the first time I am using ContentProviderClient. When I am trying to add values and my result is always returning null.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void sendHome() throws RemoteException {

    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://removed this for security of app");

    ContentProviderClient cpc = getContentResolver().acquireContentProviderClient(myUri);
    cpc.delete(myUri,null,null);
    String componentName= ComponentName.unflattenFromString(getPackageName() + "//package.name.here").flattenToShortString();

    ContentValues values= new ContentValues();

    values.put("componentName", componentName);
//other values here

    Uri result = null;
    try {

        result = cpc.insert(myUri, values);
        cpc.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (result == null) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to insert.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }

}
```

I then call this in my onCreate.

Comment: Can I look at your content provider implementation?

Comment: the uri is coming from an api from the device